How much priority is given to Air Force One?
Under normal circumstances (i.e., all normal aircraft), ATC priority is quite trivial: aircraft in distress and emergency situations goes first, then comes those who declared "fuel emergency", and then those who have already waited for a long time already, and finally, those who had just started waiting. This priority and precedence is all trivial and clear. However, when presidential aircraft comes into play, things get murkier. My question is, how exactly are incoming flights prioritized by ATC if one of them is Air Force One (or the name of the presidential aircraft in another country)? For example, will presidential aircraft get priority over aircraft who already waited a long time, aircraft who were diverted, aircraft who declared "fuel emergency", or even (hopefully not) aircraft who declared technical issues? I know full-blown emergencies ("mayday" or "pan-pan") still gets priority no matter what, but will those conditions listed above get priority or will Air Force One get priority? Can anyone (preferably ATCs) please provide some insights on this? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Just as a side note, priority is slightly less trivial than you imply. Where I work it's distress, urgency, ambulance flights, military flights expecting minimum fuel, control flights (i.e. ILS calibration), other flights (incl. scheduled air traffic) and finally sightseeing and school/training flights, except that school flights are prioritized the same as "other flights" when they are on a CAA-check (i.e. final check to obtain their license)

I would assume if there are enough other airplanes so close to AF1 that you have to worry about "priorities", something has gone horribly wrong already.

I don’t know if there are specific procedures, it is probably arrenged on national level when AF1 is expected for a visit. I once operated to an airport where AF1 was departing and basically the entire international airport was closed when the AF1 was moving. All the departing traffic waited at the gate and all the arriving traffic was in holding pattern until the thing got airborne.

Any comments from downvoters?

@60levelchange Thanks for pointing out, my list of "normal" situations is not complete. Do you suggest me to add those conditions to my list as well?

@JörgWMittag I don't think ATC would have the time and space to clear the whole airspace near where Air Force One is flying. There must always be other aircraft waiting in line behind the presidential aircraft.

Note: it depends: you wrote also about the equivalent in other countries, but it depends within the country or outside. Military aviation has own priorities (and procedures). Head of states (in foreign countries) have some security guarantee, by Vienna (so not direct on aviation, but for security reason, it may be better to have priority to leave airport quickly (the person, not the aircraft), so to reduce security and block inside apron area. Very generic and probably part of protocol, so parties will agree before a travel (which requires authorization anyway, still bc Vienna).

Why the aggressive downvoting? Can anyone please explain why this is such a bad question? I hope to make this useful to future readers, so I wish to improve my question. I'll appreciate any suggestions or direct edits. Thanks in advance!

The AIM discusses “aircraft in distress” as having ultimate priority, then “air ambulance”, then says the following about Air Force One (and similar):

Provide priority handling and expedite the movement of presidential aircraft and entourage

Priorities discussed after this are search and rescue and air intercept.
That’s it. What is distress? I’d guess it doesn’t include “aircraft that have waited a long time”.
Of course, the Secret Service is in the room with the controllers during a presidential visit, so questions about relative priority can be addressed on the spot.

Thanks for your answer! It is very helpful and informative, I learned from it. Please take my upvote as a token of my gratitude. I'm looking for more specific precedence and priority protocol given to ATC, though. Preferably a list. Still, thanks for your answer!
